# Taylor polynomial for an integral

Tags: calculus, integration, polynomials, definite-integrals, taylor-expansion

This is the first time encountering a Taylor expansion along with an integral, so I am wondering how I should proceed.

Question:

$Consider \space the \space function$

$$F(x) = \int_0^{x^2}e^{-{\sqrt{t}}} \space dt$$

$for \space any \space real \space number \space x. $

$Find \space the \space Taylor \space polynomial \space p_2(x) \space for \space the \space function \space F(x) \space centered \space at \space a=0.$

Should I first integrate the function itself and find the Taylor expansion of the result, or attempt to find the Taylor expansion with the integral attached?

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Just use the fundemental theorem of calculus with the chain rule to compute the derivatives

Comment: So I should NOT integrate first, correct? so for example, for $p_1(0)$, my result would be $2e^{-{\sqrt{0^2}}}x$?

Comment: plugging in 0 to the $F(0)$ gives you 0.   THe first derivative will be that, yes, which again gives you 0   after that you should start getting in some non zero terms

Comment: @Alan, thank you. If I may just bother you for one more second. So the final answer would look 0 + 0 + $\frac{f''(0)}{2!} (x)^2$ (whatever that results in), correct? Just making sure I am understanding my orders correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$F(x)=\int_0^{x^2} e^{-\sqrt{t}} dt$

---

METHOD $1$

$\begin{align}
F'(x)&=2xe^{-x}\\
&=2x\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^nx^n}{n!}\\
&=2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^nx^{n+1}}{n!}
\end{align}$

Integrating term by term and using $F(0)=0$ we have

$$\begin{align}
F(x)&=2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^nx^{n+2}}{(n+2)n!}\\
&=2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n(n+1)x^{n+2}}{(n+2)!}\\
&=2\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n(n-1)x^{n}}{n!}\\
\end{align}$$

---

METHOD $2$
Find $F(x)$ by evaluating its integral form and develop the power series for $F(x)$ directly.

First substitute $y^2=t$ so that $2ydy=dt$ and the new limits of integration on $y$ extend from $0$ to $x$.  Thus,

$$\begin{align}
F(x)&=\int_0^{x^2} e^{-\sqrt{t}} dt\\
&=2\int_0^{x} ye^{-y} dy\\
&=2-2(x+1)e^{-x}
\end{align}$$

where we used integration by parts to arrive at the last expression.

Thus,

$$\begin{align}
F(x)&=2-2(x+1)e^{-x}\\
&=2-2(1+x)\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^nx^n}{n!}\\
&=-2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^nx^n}{n!}-2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^nx^{n+1}}{n!}\\
&=-2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^nx^n}{n!}+2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^nx^{n}}{(n-1)!}\\
&=2\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n(n-1)x^{n}}{n!}
\end{align}$$

which agrees with the result using Method 1.

---

METHOD $3$
Develop the power series for $e^{-\sqrt{t}}$ and integrate term by term.

$$\begin{align}
F(x)&=\int_0^{x^2} e^{-\sqrt{t}} \\
&=\int_0^{x^2} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^nt^{n/2}}{n!}dt \\
&=2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^nx^{n+2}}{(n+2)n!}\\
&=2\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n(n-1)x^{n}}{n!}\\
\end{align}$$

which agrees with the results using Methods 1 and 2!

Comment: I understand what you have presented. You are adapting the Taylor expansion of $e^{-x}$ to include the variables, but now I am confused. Would my answer therefore just be $2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^nx^{n+1}}{n!}+ C$? Since this would be a representation to which we can just plug in n's? Plug in n and that's it?

Comment: Not quite.  First, you need to integrate the series for $F'$ term by term to arrive at a series for $F$.  And the integration constant can be found by using $F(0)=0$.

Comment: Of course, you could use the series for $F'$ to derive the series for $F''$, $F'''$, etc., set $x=0$ and evaluate the coefficients that way.

Comment: Best answer. I would first like to thank you so much for your time. I am reading through your explanations and there are just a couple of fundamental things I'm not understanding, so I'm doing supplementary learning right now. Thank you so much once again, studying based upon what you have showed me!

Comment: You're welcome!!  It was my pleasure.